# it-idf with TfidfVectorizer on Japanese text

Tags: python, parsing, scikit-learn, nlp, tf-idf

I am working with a huge collection of documents written in several languages. I want to compute cosine distance between documents from their tf-idf scores. So far I have:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

# The documents are located in the same folder as the script
text_files = [r'doc1', r'doc2', r'doc3'] 
files = [open(f) for f in text_files]
documents = [f.read() for f in files]

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,1))
tfidf = vectorizer.fit_transform(documents)
vocabulary = vectorizer.vocabulary_
```

When the three documents `doc1`, `doc2` and `doc3` contain English text, the algorithm works like a charm and `vocabulary` does indeed contains unigrams from the different bodies of text. I tried with Russian too, and it also worked great. However, when I try with some Japanese text, the algorithm does not work as intended anymore.

The problem arises from the fact that Japanese language does not have spaces, so that TfidfVectorizer does not understand what's a word and what isn't. For example I would have something like this in my unigram vocabulary:

> 診多索いほ権込真べふり告車クノ般宮えぼぜゆ注携ゆクく供9時ク転組けが意見だっあ税新ト復生ひり教台話辞ゃに

Whic is clearly a sentence and not a word. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: So, when you have English or Russian words, what does your `documents` list look like? Something like this: `['one', 'word', 'after', 'another']`?

Comment: Not at all, each document is a body of text. Something like: `['There are infinite universe within a grain of salt', 'Salt is very beneficial for you', 'Our universe is the only possible one']` only much longer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should provide a tokenizer for the Japanese

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,1), tokenizer=jap_tokenizer)
```

where `jap_tokenizer` is either a function you create or one like [this](https://jprocessing.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: You may want to name your tokenizer something [else](http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jap).

Comment: This is great! I ended up using [this](http://tinysegmenter.tuxfamily.org/) library instead. 

`segmenter = tinysegmenter.TinySegmenter()
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,1),tokenizer=segmenter.tokenize)`

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be the English version of `documents`, basically:

```
documents = ['one word after another', 'two million more words', 'finally almost there']
```

For your Japanese documents, call them `j_doc1`, `j_doc2`, and `j_doc3`, `documents` probably looks like this (just an example; bear with me as I didn't bother creating random Japanese sentences):

```
documents = ['診多索いほ', '診多索いほ', '台話辞ゃに']
```

The current tokenizer looks for spaces, which your string doesn't have. You could try this:

```
documents = [" ".join(char for char in d) for d in documents]
```

Now documents looks like this, which may be more feasible (although that's up to you, as I don't know whether it's appropriate to always add a space between each Japanese character):

```
documents
Out[40]: ['診 多 索 い ほ', '診 多 索 い ほ', '台 話 辞 ゃ に']
```

Or define your own tokenizer, as referred to in another answer.

Comment: This was a good answer too, thanks @not_a_robot. While not optimal, I appreciate the fact this solution is super simple to implement and it may work fine, especially when 2, 3, 4-gram are used.